# could not find member 'DataReadingMappedIfSafe' error

Tags: ios, swift

I try this code

```
 if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks") {
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
```

After swift 2.0 there is error 
could not find member 'DataReadingMappedIfSafe'

what to do?

Comment: it disappears after I change to code  let sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe) because of new error handling in swift 2.0